# Win Svr 2003: Will I be alerted if a mirrored hard drive fails?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I've never had a mirrored hard drive fail, and wonder if I will be notified by windows in the event that one of the mirrored drives fails.  Has anyone experienced this?

OS: Windows Server 2003.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the event log go to Control panel->administrative tools->event Viewer then system events

Any raid failure will have a red X next to them and will most likely mention Raid configuration\build failure or hard drive read failure.

Past that every server build I have done had a software utility that runs at bootup. For example the intel storage matrix manager or SILCFG, there are several programs out there and one should come with the motherboard in your server.

Once the raid has had a failure, the installed software manager will prompt with a notification indicating that a failure has occured and hopefully specifying the drive.

Finally on a system reboot, if it was configured through a hardware raid controller a prompt will occur stating failure before windows even loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows builtin software RAID then an event will be written to the event log.

Comment: Related question I posted a few minutes ago:

http://superuser.com/questions/91933/windows-software-raid-5-drive-failure-notification

How do we get notifications off the event log, and how do we know what event ids to key off if we haven't experienced the problem yet?

Comment: There are many programs that have the ability to monitor the event logs and send emails\alerts based on specific event types, categories, sources, etc. Your best bet is to find one that suits your needs and your budget and set it up to alert on warning and error events. Most of these programs have the ability to filter in or filter out events based on criteria that you specify. Once you've run it for awhile and had a chance to build some filters to filter out the "noise" then you'll be able to key on new events that come in and take appropriate action.